# Что делать если в консоли выводит закорючки в С++

Tags: c++

Пробовал добавить setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU"), но не помогает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main() {
system("chcp 1251 > nul");
const double kmInMile = 1.609344;
double distMile, distKm;
cout << "Укажите расстояние в ммилях: ";
cin >> distMile;
distKm = distMile * kmInMile;
cout << "Расстояние (в км): " << distKm << endl;
system("pause> nul");
return 0;
}
```